# SSRS jump to URL appends report server address to wanted URL

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm trying to create a link from a report I'm writing to a web page I've also written. The idea being that whoever is viewing the report can find the record they're interested in, then click on that entry and it will take them to the page relating to that record.

I've tried using

```
javascript:void(window.open('"+Fields!URL.Value.ToString()+"', '_blank'))
```

URL obviously being the datasource field that contains my URL. The link is clickable and does open a new tab and attempt to load a page. But the page has my report servers domain at the beginning of it (i.e. server/Reports/Pages/MyURL).

Obviously that page doesn't exist so the page doesn't (resource does not exist). Is there a way to stop window.open appending the report server to the beginning of MyURL, or is there another, better, method that I should be using instead?

Comment: is your `Fields!URL.Value` is absolute or relative?

Comment: Relative, it changes record by record.

Comment: you can try `Action > Go to URL` in properties https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157159(v=sql.100).aspx